# Spring, hibernate entity fields depending on profile

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schedules")
public class ScheduleDO {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "begin_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", 
nullable = false)
private OffsetDateTime beginTime;
}
```

And i want to be able to change the "beginTime" variable anotation based on active profile. Something like this:

```
   @Profile("dev")
   @Column(name = "begin_time_dev", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", 
   nullable = false)
   @Profile("test")
   @Column(name = "begin_time_test", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", 
   nullable = false)
   private OffsetDateTime beginTime;
```

is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually JPA/Hibernate know nothing about spring so profiles is out of their scope. Moreover entities are not beans so spring don't use them

The only solution I can see is to define a placeholder `{profile_begin_time_test}` and add an interceptor (see [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)).

In the method

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql)
```

In the sql generated by hibernate replace the `{profile_begin_time_test}` placeholder with desired real column name. The placeholder replacement can be configured to use value based on spring profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a [custom Hibernate UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom) and registering it on your `beginTime` field via the Hibernate `@Type` annotation.

In your new `UserType`, you could then get the current profile from the Spring [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) to determine the target column name. You'll have to statically register the `Environment` in your application somehow first, as your `UserType` will have been instantiated by Hibernate and won't know about your Spring application context. All doable though!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could possibly :

1)Create two different fields and different setters.

2)Add all JPA annotations on method level rather than on fields.

3)Since spring 4.1 you can profile methods, so use profiles on setters.

> The @Profile annotation may be used in any of the following ways: as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component, including @Configuration classes. As a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations. As a method-level annotation on any @Bean method

[PROFILE DOCS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

Comment: Entities are not components